# Is secure renew token using the delegation endpoint in the Auth0?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0

I want to create the single page application with token based authentication with Auth0.

My authentication use case is:

1.) Insert the username and password

2.) Get the token from Auth0 server with expiration time perhaps 6 hours

3.) In javascript side I check the expiration time of current token

4.) If the token will be before its expiration I call the function renewIdToken via Auth0.js library. It is HTTP POST to the delegation endpoint of Auth0 server.

```
auth0.renewIdToken(current_id_token, function (err, delegationResult) {
  // Get here the new delegationResult.id_token
});
```

https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js

5.) If the token will be expired then I redirect to the loginpage.

Is secure be able to renew the token via HTTP POST from anywhere? 
What's happend if the user lost the token and attacker can use this token forever because is easy to renew it and the token is not possible revoke.

This scenario is without refresh token, I only work with token.
I read some topics where is not recommended use the refresh tokens in the SPA scenario.